# Unknown error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' on ng command

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to learn Angular
I've followed the steps here: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local to get it setup on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

When I try to create a new project with ng new I get an error:

```
$ node -v
v14.12.0

$ npm -v
6.14.8

$ ng new test
Unknown error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

$ ng -v
Unknown error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I installed it via `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` which gave no errors.

I've purged node `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` and reinstalled and removed ng `sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli` then reinstalled again `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`, still get this error. Any ideas?

There was an older version of nodejs on the system originally; I upgraded to 14.x. Export is part of ES6, perhaps it's related? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: did you install angular cli?, try this `npm install -g @angular/cli` before `ng new my-app`

Comment: Yes, it is installed. I removed it with `sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli` then reinstalled it again with `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` same result.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**I had the same issue and I could fix it by downgrading node to v12.8.1**

You could use **nvm** as follows:

install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

refresh .profile

```
source ~/.profile
```

install node v12.8.1

```
nvm install v12.8.1
```

check that you are using the 12.8.1 version

```
nvm list
```

check ng again

```
ng -- version
```

Comment: You are a champion! Thanks!

Comment: Oh I had to run  `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
` Instead of `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Why nobody mentions the simple command `n 12.8.1`? This helped me to downgrade (actually, upgrade in my case) NodeJS.

Answer (score 6):

You are using an incompatible NodeJs version. Install a lower version.

More information [here](https://www.joshuacolvin.net/check-supported-node-versions-angular-cli/) ([webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924234429/https://www.joshuacolvin.net/check-supported-node-versions-angular-cli/) version).

Comment: Thats the information I was looking for. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check for node versions.
use nvm
`brew install nvm`

I had the same problem. if you have any other version of Node that might fix it
On the [Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json)
node requirement is below

```json
"engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13.0 <13.0.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.22.4"
  }
```

after installing the older version
`nvm install 12.4.0`
then
`nvm use 12.4.0`

this did the fix for me

Answer (score 0):

For me no solution worked so I uninstalled everything, both the angular and node cli, thinking that it was a version error, but when I typed `ng` in the console, the error kept appearing so I found where `ng` was, with `whereis ng`, delete the file and install all over again.

Answer (score 0):

**Run the following command on cmd**. This recommends that you always update to the latest patch version, as it contains fixes we released since the initial major release. For example, use the following command to take the **latest 10.x.x version** and use that to update.

```
ng update @angular/cli@^<major_version> @angular/core@^<major_version>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Don't run any command which is collected from here and there. Simply follow these steps.

1 uninstall current NodeJS version
2 download lowest version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).
3 install the lower NodeJS version.
4 restart cmd Promat/terminal and try.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered this error many a times in past.
What worked for was removing the package.lock and node_modules & rerun the npm install.

cached code might be causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Install a newer node version and also reinstall angular. For me it did not work with only installing a newer node.