# How to check my angular/npm/ng/tsc/ts-node is up to date with no problem with dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. I bought an Udemy course and was following the instructions. I installed everything yesterday/two days ago, so everything should be up-to-date. My versions: Angular 10.1.6, npm: 6.14.4, tsc: 4.0.3. Installed on two Windows and one Linux. The same problem as below

When i was to export the class, just like in an introduction to my course, executing ts-node command with ts file i got an error like below: (removing keyword export removes the error, any other syntax works fine)

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\sites\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1043:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\sites\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1046:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at main (C:\Users\sites\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:225:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sites\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:512:3)
```

I described my problem here: [Cant export classes/anything in typescript - unexpected token export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359717/cant-export-classes-anything-in-typescript-unexpected-token-export)

There was only one nice person, that replied to my post. The conclusion was that export is a new feature and there might be some version problem. Nonetheless, no one answered, which i find very strange, by far ive found all answers to all my questions (regarding Python, Java etc.) without even creating an account. I am total beginner and these are my first steps so this should be a trivial question with very trivial answer. I am puzzled no one can find the solution - but anyways.

If someone at least could provide me with some commands i should run (on windows, linux) to ensure:

- -which version of ng, npm, tsc, ts-node, angular, node.js i have
- -how to update them to the stable versions (versions, that dont make errors while using keyword 'export')
- -how to check if there is no problem with dependencies, some stuff that should've been installed but it isnt
- -how to check if my version of ng/tsc/whatever isnt somehow broken (weird that it was installed thrice on differens OS)
- -how to check and ensure that if a version is broken, a new one will be installed/reinstalled/updated
- -which are basic commands I should know while dealing with ng/tsc/npm and which are all things that should be installed so that typescript
  would work (in a manner in which command ts-node on ts file with key
  word export does not come with any errors)
- -any external, additional knowledge i should know as a beginners (links, whatever) while dealing with node-js, typescript, angular that might be helpful while dealing with this problem

I find it very weird that such a beginner-level, trivial typescript/angular cannot be quickly solved. I thought exporting files and just some first steps in any programming language is not a rocket science :(. I will be greatful for any assistance. If my beginner-level question IS in fact rocket science, can someone at least give me commands that i should run to ensure:

- -i have everything i need to run ts file with export
- -everything is up-to-date
- -there is no dependency issues (or any whatever they call them issues)
- -if possible, how to repair installation, if something indeed is broken.

I want to just say i was searching for similar topics and already used a lot of commands to install/update things - to no avail.

I am a beginner in JS and would be very greatful for any help. Looking forward to receiving any reply that could help me in any way. Anything that can at least help me to solve this problem or give me any clue how to deal with it whatsoever - please free to share :)

> EDIT: Never in my life have i thought running simple export command in
> TS requires Phd in Computer Science....

Comment: Might be the node version. Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051509/unknown-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export-on-ng-command

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, creating project causes no error (by command ng). I got the same error message but only when i use export word in .ts file and then try to run it by ts-node command. Already seen this topic, used the commands, nothing worked. But i will try use those commands again. Thank you for reply :)

Comment: This command nvm (on linux vm) is not even recognized even though i do everything exactly as it is in the answer to that question. EDIT: Never in my life have i thought running simple export command in TS requires Phd in Computer Science....

Comment: What I meant was related to the answers actually. Your other question shows that you have `"@types/node": "^12.11.1"` and in the one I linked it says to downgrade that to `12.8.1`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. 12.8.1 using nvm. (also created new ng project) Still, the same error: const x = 20; - no error, export const x = 20; - unexpected token export error. Funny thing btw, i have some books about C++ i know to some extent. Tbh C++ never gave me any problems whatsoever, i dont recall one time i needed to check ANYTHING (like in Python, Java) and Javascript/TS which supposed to be 'easy'. gives me such nice first steps in TS.. Words cannot describe how puzzled i am. Anyways, nvm and version 12.8.1 does not change anything :(

Comment: Hmm, I check on a project of mine that I recently updated with `ng update` and it actually has `12.11.1` of node, so that is not the problem. I would suggest trying `ng update` or `npm audit` to see if there are problems with the project and maybe also try to create a brand new app and see if that one has problems too.